# Translating PHP encryption code to C# (mcrypt_encrypt)

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I have a few lines of code in PHP and I wanna the same code in c# 
I tried to translate it by myself but I couldn't

here is my code :

```
$data = array(
  'id' => 1,
  'name' => 'Custom Login',
  'avatar' => 'http://example.com/avatar/1.png',
  'expiration' => round(microtime(true) * 1000) + 60*60*1000 // in millisecond
);

$data = json_encode($data);

$blocksize = 16;

$secret = '';
$md5 = md5($secret);

// Strictly maintains the length of key and iv
$key = substr($md5, 0, 16);
$iv = substr($md5, 16, 16);

// We need to pad the input manually to match with the server-side's padding scheme
$pad = $blocksize - (strlen($data) % $blocksize);
$data = $data . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

$encryptedSession = bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
```

I'm now familiar with PHP and the methods seem to have different functionality in PHP and c#

here's the code I've tried :

```
public static string CreateMD5(string input)
            {
                using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
                {
                    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
                    byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

                    // Convert the byte array to hexadecimal string
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
                    {
                        sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
                    }
                    return sb.ToString();
                }
            }
```

the section above for getting MD5

```
static public String EncryptRJ256(string data,int blockSize,string secret)
        {
            var md5 = CreateMD5(secret);

            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            var Key = md5.Substring(0, 16);
            var IV = md5.Substring(16,16);
            var pad = blockSize - (data.Length % blockSize);

            data = string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat((char)pad, 2));
            byte[] encrypted;
            using (var rj = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                try
                {
                    rj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    rj.KeySize = 256;
                    rj.BlockSize = blockSize;
                    rj.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
                    rj.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);

                    var ms = new MemoryStream();

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateEncryptor(rj.Key, rj.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (var sr = new StreamWriter(cs))
                        {
                            sr.Write(data);
                            sr.Flush();
                            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                        }
                        encrypted = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    rj.Clear();
                }
            }

            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        }
```

the section above for simulating php mcrypt_encrypt

any suggestion?

Comment: The PHP mcrypt extension has been deprecated, you should avoid writing new code with it.

Comment: Show us the C# code you tried...  StackOverflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @AlexHowanskyThank you for response it's a htto://chatwing.com example for integrating custom login with my website I don't know PHP I just want similar code in .NET to integrate my authentication with Chatwing

Comment: @LukeJoshuaParkI know but I couldn't finish it because functions are different and I couldn't write anything useful

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark i edited the question and added my code